# LongListSelector binding to CollectionViewSource shows empty list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I tried to use CollectionViewSource in my project and when it didn't worked I created a new empty project to simplify things. Now problem is LLS is empty. I checked event handler. e.Accepted actually evaluates to true. May be I miss something.

What I understand is every Item passed to event handler which Accepted property is true is shown in list, am I right?

MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Filtered_List_Test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="FilteredList" Source="{Binding Items}" Filter="FilteredList_Filter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">

        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="first">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FilteredList}}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>

    </phone:Pivot>

</Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Filtered_List_Test
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }

    private void FilteredList_Filter(object sender, System.Windows.Data.FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
}
}
```

Built on standart PivotApp template.

**UPD:** Further debugging line by line showed that for some reason `View` property of `CollectionViewSource` are not propagated. `Source` shows all Items, but `View` stays `null`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Its a standart PivotApp template. You can see it when You create new project. I didn't wanna clutter post with code.

Comment: Are you seeing any binding errors in Output window?

Comment: Hmm. I get only: The thread 0xabc has exited with code 259 (0x103). Googled it, nothing wrong. it is just information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a further research I findout that `LongListSelector` can't bind to `CollectionViewSource`. You have to use `ListBox` in order to bind to `CollectionViewSource`.